# Using two get and set properties for the same object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, mvp

I have a `DataGridView` in UI and my `presentation` class needs to `set` and `get` data to and from the `gird`. So that I could use a `public property` in this case as follows.

```
public DataGridView DeductionDetailsInGrid
{
    get { return dgEmployeeDeductions; }
}


public List <Deduction > DeductionDetails
{
    set { dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource = value; }
}
```

I'm using two properties here as the set property should be able to show the list of objects passed in by the presenter, on the grid and also the presenter should be able to somehow get the data from the grid to supply them for the upper layers.

Is using two get and set properties for the same `DataGridView` an acceptable solution?

I think that I should change the `get` property's data type (`DataGridView`) as exposing the `DataGridView` breaks `encapsulation`! How to do that?

EXTRA:

If using `ListBoxes` we could do something like this...

```
    public List<string>  GivenPermission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(); }
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Well, the setter is pointless, since users of this type have access to the DGV through the getter.  They can get it using the getter and set the data source without going through your property.

Comment: Thats what I want to change. But my presenter should be able to get data going through the property only.

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with `public List <Deduction > DeductionDetails
{
    get { (List<Deduction>)dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource; }
    set { dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource = value; }
}`

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, Error in your code : Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: Sorry, get should be like `get { return (List<Deduction>)dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource; }` I don't understand that's what you need. Correct me if am missing something obvious.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, Thanks, That's what I wanted to know. I'm new to .net and was not aware of that casting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List <Deduction > DeductionDetails
{
    get { return (List<Deduction>)dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource; }
    set { dgEmployeeDeductions.DataSource = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said returning a `DataGridView` back to the presenter breaks encapsulation and couples the view and the presenter. The presenter should not be aware of what control the view is using to visualize the model. The presenter simply needs to pass data to the view.

Follow the example from your setter. Return a `List<Deduction>` in the getter. You can map the list of models in the getter and then return in to the presenter

```
public List<Deduction> DeductionDetails
{
    get
    {
        List<Deduction> deductionsList = new List<Deduction>();

        foreach(var deductionFromGrid in dgEmployeeDeductions.Items)
        {
            Deduction deduction = new Deduction();
            // map properties here

            deductionsList.Add(deduction)
        }

        return deductionsList;
    }
}
```